# scope resolution operator - infinite loop?

Tags: php, loops, scope, resolution, infinite

Would this code generate an infinite loop?

```
class one{
    function ex() {
        echo "Looptext";
        one::ex2();
    }
    function ex2() {
        one::ex();
    }
}  

$one = new one;
$one->ex2();
```

I'm learning OO in php programming...

Comment: yes i tried the code at writecodeonline.com/php! But it seems that the code stops after a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two functions end up calling each other, which results in the infinite "loop" (it's not really a loop, but the result is an infinite number of method calls).

ex2() - initial call
 - calls ex()
    - calls ex2() again
        - calls ex() again

... infinite loop.

Comment: OK, thanks! But when i try the code here at this website: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ it just ends after a while. So is it really infinite?

Comment: PHP scripts only have a certain amount of time to execute. If it exceeds that amount of time, the server kills the task.

Comment: If you need to set the time limit for any reason: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Yes yes, but it says you can accept an answer in three minutes, so i have to wait ;)